# Instead of update cart button, qty should get update on click of Increment And Decrement button

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, ajax, magento2.3.1

I want to implement Ajax Cart Page : Qty should get changes on click of +/- button instead of update cart button I didn't find any article or any module to achieve this. as qty increment(+) and decrement(-)